# How shoud I do the SLAM with kinect without a robot?

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, kinect, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How shoud I do the SLAM with kinect without a robot?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49526/how-shoud-i-do-the-slam-with-kinect-without-a-robot?/) by [gggyd123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3702/gggyd123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-11-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[RGBDSlam](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam) is a possibility.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2012-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1